# Vue : Why doesn't this `this` work normally?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**case 1**

```
data(){
  return {
    serverNames : ['local']
  }
}
computed: {
    ...mapState('store', {
      local_server_name: (state) => {
        this.serverNames[0] = state.local_server_name // Cannot read property 'serverNames' of undefined
        return state.local_server_name
      },
    }),
  },
```

**case 2**

```
computed: {
        ...mapState('store', {
          local_server_name: (state) => {
            serverNames[0] = state.local_server_name // serverNames is not defined
            return state.local_server_name
          },
        }),
      },
```

In fact, appending this or not, it doesn't work. If I want to use arrow function, then how to get that `serverNames` array?

Comment: `serverNames : ['local']`

Comment: If you want to use arrow function, you need to curb this feeling because it's incorrect to use it here. Regular and arrow functions aren't interchangeable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arrow function will preserve `this` based on the scope it was defined within, which is inside the object passed as a parameter to `mapState` where `this` refers to the global object (`window`).

But that's besides the point because you shouldn't be mutating state within a computed property; this can lead to infinite re-renders and/or Vue will complain.

If you want to update component state from Vuex state then you should do so within a watcher. Maybe something like this:

```js
data() {
  return {
    serverNames: ['local']
  }
},

computed: {
  ...mapState('store', [
    'local_server_name'
  ])
},

watch: {
  local_server_name(value) {
    this.serverNames[0] = value
  }
}
```